# Cygwin環境下での静的ライブラリのリンクエラー

Tags: gcc, cygwin

研究で[TEPLA](http://www.cipher.risk.tsukuba.ac.jp/tepla/)という暗号計算ライブラリを利用しています。

WindowsでTEPLAを利用するために、Cygwinの導入とTEPLAのインストールを終え、サンプルプログラムを以下のコマンドで実行したところエラーが発生しています。

```
$ gcc sample.c -o sample -ltepla -lgmp -lcrypto
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: -ltepla が見つかりません
collect2: エラー: ld はステータス 1 で終了しました
```

静的ライブラリは`/usr/local/lib`に`libtepla.a`が存在しているのでエラーの原因がわかりません。
原因の調査法や解決法等教えていただけると嬉しいです。
よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参照しようとしているライブラリが標準パス以外にある場合は、`-L`オプションで明示的にディレクトリを追加してみてください。

今回の場合であれば`-L/usr/local/lib`を追加して

```
$ gcc sample.c -o sample -L/usr/local/lib -ltepla -lgmp -lcrypto
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事コンパイル通りました。後学のために聞きたいのですが、このコマンドは-L以下のディレクトリで静的ライブラリを探査するという認識でよろしいでしょうか...?

Comment: @sugt その理解であっています。`Cygwin`環境に限った話ではないので、詳しくは`man gcc`なども調べてみてください。